# How can I group a result set by column, date and limit the number of rows returned?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

See my other question as this one sucks:

[How can I group on the SAME table, order by date and limit the number of rows returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627286/how-can-i-group-on-the-same-table-order-by-date-and-limit-the-number-of-rows-re)

Comment: do you want `@limit` records at all or per id_field?

Comment: I would like the limit to be per ID_Field

Comment: Would you please take another look at this... it's not doing what I thought it would

Comment: please create a setup on http://sqlfiddle.com and post the link here

Comment: I have simplified my schema... the last attempt was way overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  id_field, fe.*
FROM    User_Field uf
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP (@limit)
                value, dateUsed
        FROM    Field_E2PValue fe
        JOIN    E2P_Value e
        ON      e.id = fe.id_e2pvalue
        WHERE   id_field = uf.id_field
        ORDER BY
                date_used DESC
        ) fe
WHERE   id_user = @myuser
```

Comment: Please see my question... I have tested the query and there is a little problem

Comment: @user3174075: remove the `SET ROWCOUNT` and restart the session.