# How can I group on the SAME table, order by date and limit the number of rows returned?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, sql-order-by

I would like to return a set that is grouped by ID_F, limited in count within ID_F and sorted by date within ID_F

Here is my database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[U](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_U] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[F](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_F] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[E](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[U_F_E](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ID_U] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ID_F] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ID_E] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastUsed][DateTime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_U_F_E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


declare @ID uniqueidentifier
declare @N nvarchar(50)

set @ID = '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64'
set @N = 'Bob'

insert into [U]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = '3DF035A6-C456-4AB4-8BBB-E8FF86A2A033'
set @N = 'Tom'

insert into [U]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = 'F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A'
set @N = 'F1'

insert into [F]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A'
set @N = 'f2'

insert into [F]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = '3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54'
set @N = 'f3'

insert into [F]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )


set @ID = 'EA219DA4-6C13-42AA-A1B6-DE786724A554'
set @N = 'e1'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = '6158853D-E91A-4AA4-AC0F-5D26F766C677'
set @N = 'e2'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = 'F697F78A-6990-443E-9D4B-D9BCF046DAF5'
set @N = 'e3'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = 'A7DB1FA5-28D6-4F5A-8BA0-628EA2A630A8'
set @N = 'e4'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = '8ABEE9FA-B255-4409-A2DD-30CFF62EEE3C'
set @N = 'e5'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )

set @ID = 'DA644D24-AFA5-467E-A76C-A5E94DA4FA62'
set @N = 'e6'

insert into [E]
Values(
    @ID,
    @N
    )


insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    'F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f1
    'EA219DA4-6C13-42AA-A1B6-DE786724A554', -- e1
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    '3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54', -- f3
    'EA219DA4-6C13-42AA-A1B6-DE786724A554', -- e1
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '3DF035A6-C456-4AB4-8BBB-E8FF86A2A033', -- tom
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    '8ABEE9FA-B255-4409-A2DD-30CFF62EEE3C', -- e5
    GetDate()
    )


WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    '8ABEE9FA-B255-4409-A2DD-30CFF62EEE3C', -- e5
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    'F697F78A-6990-443E-9D4B-D9BCF046DAF5', -- e3
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    '6158853D-E91A-4AA4-AC0F-5D26F766C677', -- e2
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '3DF035A6-C456-4AB4-8BBB-E8FF86A2A033', -- tom
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    'EA219DA4-6C13-42AA-A1B6-DE786724A554', -- e1
    GetDate()
    )

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
insert into [U_F_E]
Values(
    NEWID(),
    '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64', -- bob
    '220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A', -- f2
    'A7DB1FA5-28D6-4F5A-8BA0-628EA2A630A8', -- e4
    GetDate()
    )
```

TRY 0:

```
declare @limit int
set @limit = 3

declare @myuser uniqueidentifier
set @myuser = '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64'

select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser
group by ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
order by LastUsed desc
```

here is the output, notice it is grouped and sorted by date... BUT it does not limit the number of ID_F rows returned

```
ID_F                                    Name    LastUsed
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:51:45.533
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

When I try to limit the number of rows returned using this:

```
declare @limit int
set @limit = 3

declare @myuser uniqueidentifier
set @myuser = '53159BEC-88C7-48C3-B2D1-63926ED28A64'

select TOP(@limit) ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser
group by ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
order by LastUsed desc
```

I get this:

```
ID_F                                    Name    LastUsed
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537
```

When I really want this:

```
ID_F    Name    LastUsed
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537

3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

Can you help me?

TRY 1:

```
select id_f,name,lastused 
from (
select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
,dense_rank() over(partition by ID_U order by ID_F) as rnk
from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser) t
where rnk <= 3
order by lastused desc
```

returns, but does not take into account limiting rows returned:

```
id_f                                    name    lastused
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:51:45.533
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

I assume that the "3" should limit the ID_F rows returned like this?

```
id_f                                    name    lastused
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537

3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

TRY 2:

```
SELECT  id_f, fe.*
FROM    [U_F_E] uf
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP (@limit) e.Name, LastUsed
        FROM    [U_F_E] fe
        JOIN    [E] e
        ON      e.id = fe.id_e
        WHERE   id_f = uf.id_f
        ORDER BY LastUsed DESC
        ) fe
WHERE   id_u = @myuser
```

but that is WAY off ... it returns crazy number of rows.

```
id_f                                   Name LastUsed
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:55:38.870
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:55:38.870
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:55:38.870
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:55:38.870
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
```

TRY 3:

```
select id_f,name,lastused 
from (
select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
,row_number() over(partition by ID_F order by lastused desc) as rnk
from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser) t
where rnk <= @limit
order by lastused desc
```

Gives this:

```
id_f                                    name    lastused
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 07:58:54.953
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 07:51:49.560
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

but when I added another row to the table, notice 370 is NOT grouped

```
id_f                                    name    lastused
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e5  2016-04-14 08:53:21.233
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 08:50:03.187
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 08:45:00.897
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 08:43:42.253
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e2  2016-04-14 07:51:47.537
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

TRY 4:

```
select id_f,name,lastused 
from (
select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
,row_number() over(partition by ID_F order by lastused desc) as rnk
from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser) t
where rnk <= @limit
order by ID_F, lastused desc
```

Produces: (when limit is set to 3)

```
id_f                                   name lastused
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e5  2016-04-14 08:53:21.233
3708E1E8-6E7E-4E8F-B415-3F09CF22CB54    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:43.530
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 08:50:03.187
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 08:45:00.897
220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e3  2016-04-14 08:43:42.253
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e4  2016-04-14 09:00:27.780
F20AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e1  2016-04-14 07:51:42.530
```

Thank you dnoeth !

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Which release?

Comment: So you want the `top 3` rows for each user? Or the rows for the latest three users?

Comment: I want to limit the ID_F group to N number of rows

Comment: So it's #2? But why `220AD0BC-3F20-4F1C-A9B8-81AC08EA679A    e5  2016-04-14 07:51:45.533` is not included?

Comment: dnoeth - I would like to have the lastused date for the top N ID_F rows in each ID_F grouping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109181/discussion-between-dnoeth-and-user3174075).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109181/discussion-between-dnoeth-and-user3174075) it turned out that it was mainly a display issue:

```
select id_f,name,lastused 
from 
 ( 
   select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed 
      ,row_number()                   -- ranking 
       over(partition by ID_F         -- for each ID_F
       order by lastused desc) as rnk -- based on descending dates
   from [U_F_E] as ufe 
   join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID 
   where ID_U = @myuser
 ) t 
where rnk <= @limit 
order by ID_F, lastused desc -- sort the correct way :-)
```

Comment: Don't forget the 'row_number' instead of 'dense_rank'

Comment: @user3174075: Unless there are multiple rows for the same user with exactly the same `lastused` there's no difference between `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` function and check.

```
select id_f,name,lastused 
from (
select ID_F, e.Name, LastUsed
,dense_rank() over(partition by ID_U order by ID_F) as rnk
from [U_F_E] as ufe
join E as e on ufe.ID_E = e.ID
where ID_U = @myuser) t
where rnk <= 3
order by lastused desc
```

Comment: Where is the `order by LastUsed desc` logic?

Comment: i just added it at the end.

Comment: But the `TOP` is based on it.

Comment: Where is the '@limit' that returns N number of ID_F grouping?

Comment: Try `row_number() over(partition by ID_F order by lastused desc)`, this might be what OP wants.

Comment: @dnoeth..i think using `row_number` like you said would be more appropriate here. I am not sure what the OP exactly needs though.

Comment: more testing... and this does NOT work -- I just added another row to the table see question